# What does the adjective "complicated" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in my book which was:

> Their work led to a realisation that issues of injustice to women and of gender inequalities were complicated in nature.

The adjective "complicated" means "difficult to understand, analyse". But I don't think that is the sense the word has been used in here. So, what am I missing?

Comment: Why should the issues not be difficult to analyse? Perhaps injustice to women and gender inequality are not easily solved. What do **you** think the sense of the word is in your quote?

Answer (score -1):

[complicated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complicated):

> 1 : consisting of parts intricately combined
>   2 : difficult to analyze, understand, or explain